# how to Enter text '< 'and '>' for sql datasource in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I can't put this `sqlcommand` into the `SqlDataSource`.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsOperator" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>"
        SelectCommand=" select '+' id,'+' txt from dual  
                        union all select '-','-' from dual
                         union all select '*','*' from dual
                         union all select '/','/' from dual
                         union all select '>','>' from dual
                         union all select '<','<' from dual
                         union all select '%','%' from dual
                         union all select '||','||' from dual
                         union all select '=','=' from dual
                         union all select '!=','!=' from dual
                         union all select '>=','>=' from dual
                         union all select '<=','<=' from dual
                         union all select 'LIKE','IS NULL' from dual
                         union all select 'BETWEEN','BETWEEN' from dual
                         union all select 'IN','IN' from dual
                         union all select 'NOT','NOT' from dual
                         union all select 'NOT IN','NOT IN' from dual
                         union all select 'AND','AND' from dual
                         union all select 'OR','OR' from dual
                         union all select 'ANY SOME','ANY SOME' from dual
                         union all select 'ALL','ALL' from dual
                        union all select 'EXISTS','EXISTS' from dual
                        union all select 'ESCAPE','ESCAPE' from dual
                        union all select 'UNION','UNION' from dual
                        union all select 'UNION ALL','UNION ALL' from dual
                        union all select 'INTERSECT','INTERSECT' from dual
                        union all select 'MINUS','MINUS' from dual " ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection.ProviderName %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This my error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4UIr.jpg)

Comment: Would using `&gt;` and `&lt;` help?

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Please explain (as [edit] to your question) why you "can't put this". If you get any errors, please add the full error. Does this work when you remove those `<` and `>` characters? Also explain why you are querying the database for a hardcoded list of words.

Comment: I have to ask, why are there 25 pairs of values where `ID` and `TXT` are the same as each other, but then `'LIKE'` and `'IS NULL'`?

Comment: What message do you see when you hover your mouse over that green squiggly line? Can you put all that sql code into a single line (remove line breaks)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can edit it by entering `&gt;` and `&lt;`

```
asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsOperator" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>"
        SelectCommand=" select '+' id,'+' txt from dual  
                        union all select '-','-' from dual
                         union all select '*','*' from dual
                         union all select '/','/' from dual
                         union all select '&gt;','&gt;' from dual
                         union all select '&lt;','&lt;' from dual
                         union all select '%','%' from dual
                         union all select '||','||' from dual
                         union all select '=','=' from dual
                         union all select '!=','!=' from dual
                         union all select '&gt;=','&gt;=' from dual
                         union all select '&lt;=','&lt;=' from dual
                         union all select 'LIKE','IS NULL' from dual
                         union all select 'BETWEEN','BETWEEN' from dual
                         union all select 'IN','IN' from dual
                         union all select 'NOT','NOT' from dual
                         union all select 'NOT IN','NOT IN' from dual
                         union all select 'AND','AND' from dual
                         union all select 'OR','OR' from dual
                         union all select 'ANY SOME','ANY SOME' from dual
                         union all select 'ALL','ALL' from dual
                        union all select 'EXISTS','EXISTS' from dual
                        union all select 'ESCAPE','ESCAPE' from dual
                        union all select 'UNION','UNION' from dual
                        union all select 'UNION ALL','UNION ALL' from dual
                        union all select 'INTERSECT','INTERSECT' from dual
                        union all select 'MINUS','MINUS' from dual " ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection.ProviderName %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```